# SharePoint XAML Workflow - REST ISODateString to DateTime

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2015

I'm designing a SharePoint-hosted add-in declarative workflow.
I'm calling a REST endpoint that returns me a DateTime value and I need to compare this date to current DateTime that I get using DateTime.UtcNow.

When looping thru my httpsend response, I've tried to:

- Convert.ToDateTime(itemDate)
- DateTime.Parser(itemDate)

but both throw error.

How can I get this working to compare dates?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've found the error: there were a null value in one itemDate in the JSON response. So I simple did a String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemDate) and it worked.

Comment: what error u are getting?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, I found the problem. Inspected the exception, there were a null value in my dataset. A simple String.IsNullOrEmpt solved the issue.